# How to get checkbox value and change tht button's class with <aura:if>?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, aura-if

I want to change the button's style (class) by clicking and changing checkbox field `Selected__c`. But I always get `class="blueColor"` even if checkbox is `true`. When I write `<aura:if isTrue="{!v.object.Selected__c == true}">` - result is the same.

Here is my code.

**cmp:**

```
    <aura:attribute name="objects" type="Object__c[]"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.objects}" var="object" indexVar="index">     
        <div data-index="{!index}" aura:id="changeIt" class="slds-panel__body">
            {!object.Name}
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.object.Selected__c}">
                <lightning:button aura:id="buttonSelectId" label="Select" name="{!object}" class="grayColor" disabled="true"/>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    <!-- "c.select" is for "v.object.Selected__c = true", so the status changes  -->
                    <lightning:button aura:id="buttonSelectId" label="Select" name="{!object}" class="blueColor" onclick="{!c.select}"/>
                </aura:set>
            </aura:if>
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
```

**js:**

```
   select : function(component) {
        let selectApex = component.get("c.selectApex");
        let object = event.getSource().get("v.name");

        selectApex.setParams({
            "selected" : true,
            "objectId" : object.Id
        });

        selectApex.setCallback(this,function(response){
            let state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                console.log("YES!");
            }else {
                console.log("NO: " + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(selectApex);
    },
```

**apex:**

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Object__c selectApex(Boolean selected, Id objectId) {
        Object__c selectedO = [SELECT Id, Selected__c FROM Object__c WHERE Id =: objectId];
        selectedO.Selected__c = selected;
        update selectedO;
        return selectedO;  
    }
```

What should I change to get right colors for my button if `Selected__c` is `true` or `false`?

Comment: [$A.utils.toggleClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm) should do the trick instead of using aura:if/else in your markup

Comment: in your select function you are calling the even parameter but you didnt pass it in the  functions parameters select : function(component, event, helper) {
so you won't ever populate the objectId variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`object`, the iteration variable for your `<aura:iteration>`, is not part of the `v.` value provider:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.object.Selected__c}">
```

You should have simply `{! object.Selected__c }` here. The expression you have never evaluates to `true` (because `v.object` doesn't exist), so your `else` branch always renders.

It's often easier to use conditional expressions in your component attributes rather than the heavy `<aura:if>`. You can set your style class conditionally thus:

```
<lightning:button ... class="{! object.Selected__c ? 'grayColor' : 'blueColor' }" ... />
```